# Erro Função Delete kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

O código é esse

```
fun delete(id: Int) {
        if (!customerRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw Exception()
        }
        customerRepository.deleteById(id)

    }
```

O erro é esse:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'id' is 
present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being 
declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper
for the corresponding primitive type.
```

Pesquisei um monte, mas não achei uma resposta que solucionasse esse problema.

Como o erro é sobre tipo primitivo, tentei mudar forçando para Integer e continuou dando esse erro de nulidade mesmo, eu definindo na model do projeto, que pode ser sim, valores nulos ou não nulos, famoso `var id: Int? = null`

Comment: Eu estou votando para fechar esta pergunta porque já foi feita aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/593189/problema-de-nullabilidade-em-kotlin-com-springboot